# Echo framework CSRF validation not working with form submission

Tags: go, csrf, csrf-token

I am trying to implement CSRF protection for a login form using the Echo framework in Go. I am using the c.Validate method to validate the CSRF token, but even when the error returned is nil, the code still triggers an "Invalid CSRF token" error. I have tried changing the variable name and using different token lookups, but the error persists. How can I fix this issue and successfully validate the CSRF token in my login form using Echo?

Go Code:

```
e := echo.New()
e.Use(middleware.CSRFWithConfig(middleware.CSRFConfig{
  TokenLookup: "form:_csrf",
}))
e.GET("/sign-in", func(c echo.Context) error {
  return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "sign-in.html", map[string]interface{}{
    "csrf":  c.Get(middleware.DefaultCSRFConfig.ContextKey),
  })
}).Name = "signin"
e.POST("/login", func(c echo.Context) error {
  // Validate CSRF token
  csrfErr := c.Validate(middleware.DefaultCSRFConfig.TokenLookup + ":form:_csrf")
  if csrfErr != nil {
    return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusUnauthorized, "Invalid CSRF token")
  }

  // Rest of the code
}).Name = "login"
```

Html Code:

```
<form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{.csrf}}">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="your@email.com" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label"> Password </label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-flat">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried changing the variable name, using different token lookups and make sure the error varaible is nill, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the lines below. Just remove them.

```golang
// Validate CSRF token
csrfErr := c.Validate(middleware.DefaultCSRFConfig.TokenLookup + ":form:_csrf")
if csrfErr != nil {
    return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusUnauthorized, "Invalid CSRF token")
}
```

The following code registers the CSRF middleware. And as a middleware, it validate the requests before your handler is executed. If the request reaches your handler, it means that the CSRF token is valid. If in doubt, see [the implementation](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/a7802ea523e56c79a1b9e9620c48d68bcff5212e/middleware/csrf.go#L154-L161).

```
e.Use(middleware.CSRFWithConfig(middleware.CSRFConfig{
    TokenLookup: "form:_csrf",
}))
```

And here is the doc for `Validate`:

```
// Validate validates provided `i`. It is usually called after `Context#Bind()`.
// Validator must be registered using `Echo#Validator`.
Validate(i interface{}) error
```

It's not for validating CSRF token. Instead, it's used to validate a data binding (see [Binding Request Data](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/)). And in your case, the error is `ErrValidatorNotRegistered`, which means `(data binding) validator not registered`.